# Get month dates and name of days

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get the name of the day and the dates of the current month. Can anyone help ?

I want in respective format.

```
Date          Day
2018-04-01    Sunday
2018-04-02    Monday
2018-04-03    Tuesday
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
2018-04-30    Monday
```

Comment: This is trivial if you have a `calendar table`

Answer (score 3):

One way to get the results that you want is to use a recursive CTE:

```
with dates as (
      select datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1) as dte
      union all
      select dateadd(day, 1, dte)
      from dates
      where day(dateadd(day, 1, dte)) <> 1
     )
  select dte, datename(weekday, dte)
  from dates;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/12846) is a SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

MJH is right, if you want stuff like this, use a Calendar table. For example: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/calendar/145206/

Then your SQL becomes as trivial as

```
SELECT CalendarDate, [DayName]
FROM CalendarTable
WHERE CalendarDate BETWEEN CONVERT(date, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,GETDATE()),0)) AND CONVERT(date, DATEADD(DAY, -1,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,GETDATE()) +1,0)));
```

or possibly even:

```
SELECT CalendarDate, [DayName]
FROM CalendarTable
WHERE CalenderMonth = MONTH(GETDATE())
  AND CalendarYear = YEAR(GETDATE());
```